# Multithreading Output Confusion

Tags: c, multithreading

Consider the following part in main

```
     tcount = 0;
     for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
      count[i] = 0;
      if (pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, randint, (void *)&i) != 0) {
           exit(1);
      } else {
           printf("Created Thread %d\n", i);
      }
//        XXXXXXX
     }

     for (i=0; i<nthreads; i++) {
      printf("Waiting for thread %d to terminate\n", i);
      pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
     }
```

and the randint code is:

```
void *randint(void *pint)
{
     int j, k;
     int rseed;

     j = *((int *)pint);
     printf("Started thread %d\n", j);
     while (tcount++ < NMAX) {
      count[j] += 1;
     }
     return(NULL);
}
```

### The Output is:

```
Created Thread 0
Created Thread 1
Waiting for thread 0 to terminate
Started thread 0
Started thread 0
Waiting for thread 1 to terminate
```

I am confused why in the output there is:

```
Started thread 0
Started thread 0
```

I understand if it was:

```
Started thread 0
Started thread 1
```

Or:

```
Started thread 1
Started thread 1
```

But the 2 zeros is not clear !!!
Any guess ???

Comment: You're passing the address of a local variable `i` to a thread... there's no guarantee that `i` is even still in scope at the time you read from it in the thread, never mind with the value you expect.

Comment: ..and re-using the variable i in the join loop, so resetting it to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if (pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, randint, (void *)&i) != 0) {
```

This is passing in the *address* of `i` when you should pass in its value.  Typically we just pass in the integer as a `void *` as a hack.

```
if (pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, randint, (void *)i) != 0) {
...
// in the thread we cast the void * back to an int (HACK)
j = (int)pnt;
```

The reason why `i` gets reset to 0 is that you are re-using `i` in the next loop:

```
for (i=0; i<nthreads; i++) {
  printf("Waiting for thread %d to terminate\n", i);
  pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
}
```

But even if you used `j` in this loop here, you would not get `Started thread 0` and then `1` because by the time the thread starts, the value of `i` has probably changed because the `pthread_create(...)` takes a relatively long time.  If you used `j` in the second loop you would probably get:

```
Started thread 1
Started thread 1
```

Passing in `i` by *value* to the thread is the right thing to do here.  If it needs to be an address then you should allocate space for a copy of it:

```
int *pnt = malloc(sizeof(i));
*pnt = i;
if (pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, randint, (void *)pnt) != 0)
...
// remember to free it inside of the thread
```